# decimal in tkinter calculator

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.
Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.
Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.
Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.
Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.
Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.
Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.
Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.
Here is a fully working calculator.
For those who need it.

```
 from tkinter import *
from math import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Simple Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)



def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

def button_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "addition"
    f_num = float(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_equal():
    global f_num
    second_number = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    if math == "addition":
        e.insert(0, f_num + float(second_number))
    if math == "subtraction":
        e.insert(0, f_num - float(second_number))
    if math == "multiplication":
        e.insert(0, f_num * float(second_number))
    if math == "division":
        e.insert(0, f_num / float(second_number))
    if math == "comma":
        e.insert(0,f_num +  + float(second_number))
    if math == "squere":
        e.insert(0, f_num ** int(2))
    if math == "sroot":
        e.insert(0, sqrt(f_num) )



def button_subtract():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "subtraction"
    f_num = float(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)



def button_multiply():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "multiplication"
    f_num = float(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_divide():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "division"
    f_num = float(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)

def button_comma():
    global f_num
    first_number = e.get()
    f_num=str(first_number)
    s_num = e.get()
    e.insert(0, str(f_num) +  str(".")  + str(s_num))

def Button_num(number):
    current=e.get()
    e.delete(0,END)
    e.insert(0,str(current)+ str(number))

def Button_squeree():
    global math
    global f_num
    first_number = e.get()
    f_num = int(first_number)
    math="squere"
    current=e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0,int(current) ^ int(first_number))

def Button_sroott():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "sroot"
    f_num = float(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)



#Sredi zarez!
'''   
def button_comma():
    current = e.get()
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(","))



Button_comma = Button(root, text="," ,padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_comma())
Button_comma.grid(row = 7 , column = 0 )
'''


# Definisi tastere
Button1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
Button2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
Button3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))

Button4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
Button5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
Button6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))

Button7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
Button8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
Button9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))

Button0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))
Button_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=38, pady=20, command=button_add)
Button_equal = Button(root, text="=", padx=87, pady=20, command=button_equal)

Button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=77, pady=20, command=button_clear)
Button_subtract = Button(root, text="-", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_subtract)
Button_multiply = Button(root, text="*", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_multiply)

Button_divide = Button(root, text="/", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_divide)
btn_decimal = Button(root, text=u'\u002E', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda:Button_num("."))
Button_squere = Button(root,text="^",padx=40,pady=20,command=Button_squeree)

Button_sroot =  Button(root, text="r",padx=40, pady=20, command=Button_sroott)
'''
Button_comma = Button(root, text="." , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=button_comma)
'''

# stavi tastere na ekran
Button1.grid(row=3, column=0)
Button2.grid(row=3, column=1)
Button3.grid(row=3, column=2)

Button4.grid(row=2, column=0)
Button5.grid(row=2, column=1)
Button6.grid(row=2, column=2)

Button7.grid(row=1, column=0)
Button8.grid(row=1, column=1)
Button9.grid(row=1, column=2)

Button0.grid(row=4, column=0)
Button_add.grid(row=5, column=0)
Button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)

Button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
Button_subtract.grid(row=6, column=0)
Button_multiply.grid(row=6, column=1)

Button_divide.grid(row=6, column=2)
btn_decimal.grid(row=7,column=0)
Button_squere.grid(row=7,column=1)


Button_sroot.grid(row=7 , column=2)








root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If we ignore the indentation errors, it looks like you've succeeded in creating a comma button. Why do you think this code doesn't work?

Comment: you need to have code under the `button_comma()` subroutine, otherwise it will thing the `Button_comma = Button(....` is part of the function. For now you can just put `pass` to see if the lines under it run fine.

Comment: Well,
When I try to use my calculator and for example press 5,5 and + 5 the result will not be 10,5. The result will be 5,55. That is the problem I am trying to solve.
I didn't say it well in the title of a question, I managed to create a button, but what I don't know is what to type in button_comma(), to make it work.

Comment: `def button_comma():
    global f_num
    first_number = e.get()
    f_num=str(first_number)
    s_num = e.get()
    e.insert(0, str(f_num) +  str(".")  + str(s_num))
 `

Comment: I tried with this, but when I press 5 and "." it just copies  5.

Comment: Why don't you put the code in comment into your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it no longer contains a question, and isn’t well-suited for Stack Overflow’s Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I see your doubt and yeah it's a valid thing according to me and the first thought was to use unicode symbol '.', which here works for you. So, I will just keep the part of code you would need and work your way.

```
def Button_num(number):#although i kept the paramater as a number, you can use this
current=e.get()
e.delete(0,END) #if you want to delete the first number while getting second one
e.insert(0,str(current)+ str(number))    

#creating button for it 
btn_decimal=Button(root,text=u'\u002E',padx=20,pady=10,command=lambda:Button_num("."))
button_decimal.grid(row=5,column=2)#fill urs
```

So, this would allow you to create the decimal symbol as well as use it but check that the inputs are set to float.

Use this video for future reference on unicodes
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_8sPENjHw4

Mind me if I overdid the answer, this is first time answering and still learning clean code.

Comment: I made a mistake, I wrote str(), instead of float().Thank you, dude. <3

Comment: haha, it happens, ur welcome, and the channel in the link, he also makes a calculator, check it out.